# delete data in listview sqlite

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview

My app is crashing need help to fix it.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


DatabaseHelper myDB;
Button btnAdd;
Button btnList;
TextView tvView;
EditText editText;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
    btnList = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnList);
    tvView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Textview);
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    myDB=new DatabaseHelper(this);



    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String newEntry = editText.getText().toString();
            if (newEntry.length() != 0) {
                AddData(newEntry);
                editText.setText("");
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You must put something in the text field", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

    });
    btnList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListDataActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}


public void AddData(String newEntry) {
    boolean insertData = myDB.addData(newEntry);
    // check inserted successfully
    if (insertData == true) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Successfully Entered Data!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

}

ListDataActivity.java

```
public class ListDataActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


DatabaseHelper myDB;
ListView listView;
ArrayAdapter<String>listAdapter;



@Override
protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_layout);

    listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    myDB= new DatabaseHelper(this);


    //populate an ArrayList<String> from the databases and then view it
   ArrayList<String> theList=new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor data=myDB.getListContent();

    if(data.getCount()==0){
        Toast.makeText(ListDataActivity.this,"The database was empty",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else{
        while(data.moveToNext()){
            // get the value from the database in column 1
            // then add it to the ArrayList
            theList.add(data.getString(1));
            // create the list adapter and set the adapter
            listAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,theList);
            listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

            // set an onItemClickListen to the listView
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    String name=adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();


                    Cursor data=myDB.getItemID(name); //get the id assosicated with the name
                    int itemID=1;
                    while(data.moveToNext()){
                        itemID=data.getInt(0);
                    }
                    if(itemID > -1){
                        Intent editScreenIntent=new Intent(ListDataActivity.this,EditDataActivity.class);
                        editScreenIntent.putExtra("id",itemID);
                        editScreenIntent.putExtra("name",name);
                        startActivity(editScreenIntent);
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(ListDataActivity.this, "No ID assosciated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }
            });


        }

    }
}
```

}

EditDataActivity.java

```
public class EditDataActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button btnDelete;
EditText etDelete;
DatabaseHelper myDB;
String selectedName;
int selectedID;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.edit_data_layout);
    btnDelete=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);
    etDelete=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    myDB=new DatabaseHelper(this);

    // get the intent extra from the ListDataActivity
    Intent receivedIntent=getIntent();

    // now get the itemID we passed as an extra
    selectedID=receivedIntent.getIntExtra("id",-1);//NOTE -1 it just a default values

    // now get the name we passed as an extra
    selectedName=receivedIntent.getStringExtra("name");

    //set the text to show the current selected name
    etDelete.setText(selectedName);

    btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            myDB.deleteName(selectedID,selectedName);
            etDelete.setText("");
            Toast.makeText(EditDataActivity.this, "removed from datebase", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });



}
```

}

DatabaseHelper.java

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

```
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mylist.db";
public  static final String TABLE_NAME = "mylist_data";
public static final String COL1 = "ID";
public static final String COL2 = "ITEM1";

public DatabaseHelper(Context context){
    super (context, DATABASE_NAME, null , 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String createTable = " CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME +"(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
           " ITEM1 TEXT)";
            db.execSQL(createTable);



}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP IF TABLE EXITS "+ TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);




}
public boolean addData(String item1) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL2, item1);


    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

    //if date as instered incorrectly it will return -1
    if (result == -1) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
    /**
     * Return all the data from database
     * @return
     */
    public Cursor getListContent() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor data =db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME,null);
    return data;


}
/**
 * Returns only the ID that matches the name passed in
 * @param name
 * @return
 */
public  Cursor getItemID(String name){
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT "+ COL1 +" FROM "+TABLE_NAME+
            " WHERE "+ COL2 +" = '"+ name +"'";
    Cursor data = db.rawQuery(query,null);
    return data;
}


/**
 * Delete from database
 * @param id
 * @param name
 */
public void deleteName(int id, String name){
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query= "DELETE FROM "+ TABLE_NAME +" WHERE " + COL1 + " = '"
            + id + "'"+" AND " + COL2 + "= '" + name + "'";
    db.execSQL(query);

}
```

}

Layout

```
<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/etDelete" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:ems="10" 
    android:inputType="textPersonName" /> 

<Button android:id="@+id/btnDelete" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Delete" />
```

LogCat Show:

```
12-28 02:32:39.527 15020-15020/sg.edu.rp.c346.todolist E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering
12-28 02:34:22.487 15020-15020/sg.edu.rp.c346.todolist E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                         Process: sg.edu.rp.c346.todolist, PID: 15020
                                                                         java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{sg.edu.rp.c346.todolist/sg.edu.rp.c346.todolist.EditDataActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
                                                                             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                          Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                             at sg.edu.rp.c346.todolist.EditDataActivity.onCreate(EditDataActivity.java:42)
                                                                             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
                                                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
                                                                             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: It seems that you've used RippleDrawable according to your logcat, but you didn't imported it well on the gradle that's why it can't find. OR the file is missing

Comment: how to slove ? i did't do anythingin gradle or import anything

Comment: 12-28 02:43:01.257 24354-24360/? E/jdwp: Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
12-28 02:43:01.267 24354-24354/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering

Comment: @Junhao which one is line 42 of EditDataActivity.java?

Comment: etDelete.setText(selectedName); this line?

Comment: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{sg.edu.rp.c346.todolist/sg.edu.rp.c346.todolist.EditDataActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: @Junhao can u post edit_data_layout.xml layout?

Comment: Try als to log the variable: selectedName

Comment: put EditDataActivity xml

Comment: @Junhao when u load the screen itself app is crashing or when click on the button its crashing?

Comment: when i click it to the next activity which is EditDataActivity .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is Here :

```
etDelete = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
```

Change to :

```
etDelete = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDelete);
//-----------------------------------------^
```